# Are dryer extension cords legal and safe?

Tags: electrical, dryer, appliances, stacked-washer-dryer

I recently stacked my dryer on top of my washer only discover that, from the dryer's new position, its cord was just a few inches too short to reach its outlet.

What to do? One option is to move the outlet, but I’d like to avoid this as it would involve expense and hassle (e.g. getting my landlord’s approval).

I'm curious about using an extension cord with the dryer. (Such as [this one](https://www.amazon.ca/Extension-N14-30P-N14-30R-Charging-14-30P/dp/B0976XHVSB))

Several questions:
Would this pose any safety issues? If so, how can they be mitigated?

Could this pose legal issues, or complications with apartment or building insurance?  If so, where might I look for more information?

Curiously, where I live - Quebec, Canada - dryer cords all seem to be 4.5 feet long. I'm unclear on why longer ones aren't readily available. If this is due to a law or regulation, where might I look to get details about it?

Several comments and an answer suggest swapping the existing cord for a longer one. I'd put this idea aside because the dryer is an LG and seems to use non-standard connectors for the cable. Here's a picture of the access panel:

[image: the access panel]

The dryer cords I've seen online all seem to use moulded ring terminals, which these are not. Does anyone know what these white plastic connectors are called?  How would I search for a dryer cable with this type of connector?

For anyone curious about the access panel / power cord terminals on an LG DLE3500W, here are a few photos.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check out amazon for dryer cords, at least three on first page running from six to ten feet and less than half cost of the extension.

Comment: I see 30 A cords 6 ft in length with NEMA 14-30 plug advertised on Amazon. I would think this would be much cheaper and better than getting a 10 ft long extension cord giving you 14.5 ft of cord piled up. Maybe go to a real electrical supply outlet.

Comment: Just make sure if ordering from Amazon that it says UL or ETL or equivalent *and that the cord when it arrives is labeled UL or ETL or equivalent.* (Not: FCC, CE, etc.)

Comment: What's the model # of your dryer?   I've never seen one like that with plugs instead of terminals and I'm not sure why anyone would build a dryer that way, making it unattractive to anyone with a hard-wired installation.    The seller's installer shows up, fails, and tells you to call an electrician before he comes back?  That's nuts.

Comment: Model number is DLE3500W

Comment: The US manual for that model describes and pictures a screw-down terminal block and procedures for installing different cords or hard wiring. The Canadian version of the manual has no illustrations, does not provide for hard wiring or for 3-wire connection, but it says that the dryer comes without a cord and talks about both screw-down terminals and plug connections ambiguously.   Do the four wires in your picture go directly to the cable and strain relief?  What's the shiny thing at the right side of the picture?  Ask your retailer if/why the documentation is incorrect.

Comment: Can you take another maybe from the side to see how those plastic connectors are attached to the dryer.  If those wires are just screwed on behind there life might not be difficult.

Comment: Inspectors cite 400.12 prohibiting "cord sets" as permeant wiring.

Answer (score 3):

Legal? Probably. Safe? Not in the long-term.

There are a few issues with extension cords in general:

- Tripping hazard - presumably not an issue here
- Heat, if used improperly - e.g., while wrapped up on a cord reel. This can cause a fire.
- More connections = more possible problems. This is true the larger the load gets. So it is a huge issue with EV charging, hardly an issue at all with very small loads (e.g., typical lights, phone chargers, etc.) and potentially a real issue with a dryer (~ 24A for an hour). In fact, I prefer hardwired appliances when possible as that gets rid of an otherwise detachable/movable problem.

Unfortunately, it looks like the connections for the LG model DLE3500W dryer require a special power cord, the LG 6411EL1001B, or equivalent, which so far I have only found in the ~ 4.5 foot length. Hacking together your own cord is generally not a good idea.

If you can't find a suitable replacement cord, then the alternative is to get an electrician (because this is an apartment you need a licensed professional) to move the circuit. Depending on the particular setup, that may be super easy or it may involve using the existing box as a junction to a short piece of cable that extends to a new box with the receptacle.

---

*Original answer, which as far as I know applies to most other brands - GE, Whirlpool, etc. - apparently does not apply to at least some LG dryers that have a proprietary connector instead of the usual screw terminals. This advice still answers the title question for most brands of dryers.*

But really, there is an incredibly simple solution. **Replace the cord/plug.** Unlike many appliances, the cord/plug on a dryer is *designed* to be replaceable. They don't ship from the factory with a cord, because there are so many variables:

- Length - should be long enough that the dryer can be pulled away from the wall safely, but not much longer than that.
- 3-wire (10-30) vs. 4-wire (14-30)
- Not for most US/Canada dryers, but for some other appliances: 6-30 (no neutral) vs. 14-30 (with neutral)

In searching a little online at big box stores *in Canada*, it seems that most are 4.5 - 4.9 feet or listed as 1.5 meters. But I have found some longer ones available for delivery. Just keep looking, or go to a traditional hardware store and they'll pull one out of a dusty bin in the back.

Comment: Thank you so much for this thoughtful answer!  Replacing the cord is slightly complicated due to terminals required on the end. See my edit. Do you have any additional advice in light of the edit info (LG dryer, non-ring terminals)?

Comment: OMG! Found that this is officially part # 6411EL1001B $161 from LG Canada, $87 on Amazon. That's one heck of a vendor lock-in problem, and to be honest quite absurd. GE, Whirlpool, etc. - all the same, and 3rd-party cords available as well from many legitimate manufacturers. LG...not so much.

Comment: OP hosed.  :) Extension cord idea aging well.

Comment: @jay613 Maybe, maybe not. Those connectors from the machine seem to be hanging from wires. Will depend where those wires go.  Really it is LG that is the hoser

Comment: Any reason not to just cut the terminals off the ends of the existing cord and splice them to a new cord with wire nuts or wagos?

Answer (score 1):

Just dealing with the extension cord part of the question. Many codes do not allow extension cords for permanent installation. In addition to this, most manufacturers have a clause, warning, in their installation procedures that state not to use extension cords to operate the dryer. Doing this could allow insurance companies to deny any claims where the dryer may be at fault.